# ng-paste brings model before it's pasted

Tags: angular, ng-paste

Let's say I have

```
<input type="text" ng-paste="foo(v)" ng-model="v">
```

and

```
$scope.foo = function(val) {
    console.log(val);
}
```

I get 'undefined' on console.

I think it's because when the moment ng-paste is called, model is still 'undefined' and then pasted value is coming after.

How can I use pasted strings using ng-paste?

Comment: You want to angularjs or angular 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :

Angularjs :

**template.html**

```
<input type="text" ng-paste="foo($event)" ng-model="v">
```

**controller.js**

```
$scope.v = "";

$scope.foo = function(e) {
    console.log(e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'));
}
```

Angular 2

**template.html**

```
<input type="text" (paste)="foo($event)" [(ngModel)]="v">
```

**component.ts**

```
v: any;

foo(e) {
    console.log(e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So the problem was, the moment ng-model is changed is coming after foo is called?